# send texts and pdf file to server from android app

Tags: android, pdf, server

i try to send group of edit texts and PDF file to server when user clicks on button . i succeeded in send group of texts alone without pdf , then i succeeded in send pdf without texts. i want to send both of them on same url in same time  how to do that
         code of text

```
      private class postData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      // private final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
     //       "Saving data to server. Please wait...", true);
    EditText email = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    EditText phone = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    String eemail=email.getText().toString();
    String pphone=phone.getText().toString();
    EditText first  = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    EditText second= (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    String firstname=first.getText().toString();
    String lastname=second.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // perform long running operation operation

        // SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, 0);
        //String server = settings.getString("server", "");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://phone.tmsline.com/api/request_job");
        String json = "";
        String responseStr="";
        String result="true";


        try {
            // Add your data

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", eemail));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", pphone));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cv","not now"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", firstname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lastname));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            try {
                httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("HTTP Failed", e.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String responseStr) {
        super.onPostExecute(responseStr);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),responseStr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(responseStr.equals("true")){
            // Update your Button here
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"done finally",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

code of pdf

```
public  void filetest(){
    String url = "http://phone.tmsline.com/api/";
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
            "Sherouk adel.pdf");
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                new FileInputStream(file), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        //HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //Do something with response...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // show error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using all this it's better you check Async Task with it you can send the EditText data PDF together else you can send EditText data first then in the postExecute method you can send PDF.